# Does an inequality in $x$ and $y$ imply $x$ and $y$ are real numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does an inequality in $x$ and $y$, such as $x < y$, imply $x$ and $y$ are real numbers?

It sort of seems obvious: two complex numbers can't be less than or greater than each other (e.g. you can't say if $3i + 1 < i + 7$, right?). But, I don't know if you need state that — for example $x$ and $y$ are real numbers before $x < y$, if this has not been implied by something else you've said.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's usual to state what the variables you're working with actually are, it doesn't matter if it's before or just after the first time you use them. Because you could be talking about integers, or any ordered set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better style to always specify the sets your numbers came from. But inequalities between complex numbers indeed don’t make sense (unless you define what you mean first), so it’s a good bet that those numbers are implicitly real.

A very common case is specifying that certain numbers are positive or writing $a > 0$. Even if you generally talk about complex numbers, this is understood to mean that these numbers are real (and positive, of course).